# Adding Input Text Box in list-group-item along with Text

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to add a Input TextBox in list-group-item List along with the ListItem Text.
I have shown the requirement in the attached picture.
So ListItem 1.. will represent a text lets say Product Name and I want to show an textbox in-front of it to get quantity against it.

[image: Required UI]
 `<div class="list-group" data-url="/Controller/GetMothod" id="list-Item" role="tablist">

     <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" data-toggle="list" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="home" >List Item 1</a>
     <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="home" >List Item 2</a>
     <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="home" >List Item 3</a>
     <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="home" >List Item 4</a>
     <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-toggle="list" href="#" role="tab" aria-controls="home" >List Item 5</a>
    </div>`

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you are asking exactly, but try this:

```
<li class="list-group-item">List Item 1 <input type="text" /></li>
<li class="list-group-item">List Item 2 <input type="text" /></li>
```